# Canvas - Rotating my images(circles)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I currently have a bunch of circles that i fill with a image inside a "box", they are bouncing and colliding. Now I want them to **rotate**.
I have tried to get this to work but I only seem to be able to rotate the entire canvas, I only want the balls to rotate.

This is my render-function:

```
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = function() {
  render();
  console.log("asdsad");
  }

  img.src = "xxx.png";

  function render() {
  var ball;
  for (var i = 0; i <balls.length; i++) {
     ball = balls[i];
     ball.x = ball.nextx;
     ball.y = ball.nexty;
     context.drawImage(img, ball.x - (img.width/2), ball.y - (img.height/2));     
  }
```

}

GOAL: Get these balls to rotate.

**EDIT**: I have tried something like this, obviously I'm doing something wrong.

```
     context.rotate(Math.PI/180); // Should this be another value? Either way, entire canvas rotates.
     context.drawImage(img, ball.x - (img.width/2), ball.y - (img.height/2));
     //context.rotate(-Math.PI/180)
     context.restore();
```

[image: balls]

Comment: What does this have to do with three.js?

Comment: It doesn't. I have edited my tags. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there with your code. You are only forgetting the actual angle:

If you want something easy to wrap the head around and use angles in degrees you can do:

```
context.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

a trick here is to pre-calculate `Math.PI / 180` and use that to calculate:

```
var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
...
context.rotate(angle * deg2rad);
```

Then draw the balls.

You probably already know but just in case (as it isn't in the example you provided) - To use `restore` you must first use `save`:

```
context.save();
context.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
context.drawImage(img, ball.x - (img.width * 0.5), ball.y - (img.height * 0.5));
context.restore();
```

**Update**:

I made an example with a single ball. Just apply the principle for many.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/RseAh/)**

The main loop goes like this:

```
/// pre-setup done (see demo)

function loop() {

    /// change direction if at some edge    
    if (x < r || x > ez.width - r) {
        dx = -dx;
        angleDelta = -angleDelta; /// dummy bounce
    }
    if (y < r || y > ez.height - r) {
        dy = -dy;
    }

    /// clear previous ball
    ctx.clearRect(x - r - 2, y - r - 2, img.width + 4, img.height + 4);

    /// move and rotate
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    angle += angleDelta;

    /// save context
    ctx.save();

    /// move to ball's center position
    ctx.translate(x, y);

    /// rotate at balls center position
    ctx.rotate(angle);

    /// draw ball offset so center is center of image
    ctx.drawImage(img, -r, -r);

    /// reset translation and rotation
    ctx.restore();

    ///again
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Comment: Ken - Thanks for the response, great as always. This however I don't get to work. My balls just bounce around like they did before. I don't notice any difference. There is no rotation to the balls when they bounce around. No errors in the code. If i remove save/restore i can see the canvas rotating. I wish I could show the entire code, but its like 250 lines. Can't really post that here

Comment: Hmm, the only thing that seems to happen is that my "walls", or my box is moved. So the balls go out side my box.

Comment: @CheesePuffs you need of course to increment your `angle` (you're not showing in the post if/how you do this). Or the angle's gonna stay the same = no rotation. Please see my updated answer which now contains a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have tried:

```
context.rotate(Math.PI/180);
```

As known in mathematics PI = 180 degree and if you do PI / 180 = 1 degree it will do nothing except a little.
So if you want to rotate the canvas 90 degree you have to write:

```
context.rotate(Math.PI/2);
```

if you want 180 degree you have to:

```
context.rotate(Math.PI);
```

and carry on.
with some calculation you will be able to rotate it to any degree you want.

if this does not work you can try this alternative

this function take the arguments and buld the image for you in a simple way that you can understand it might help someone out their.
this function help you

```
function drawImg(img, pX, pY, oX, oY, w, h, rot , context2D) {
context2D.save();
context2D.translate(pX+oX, pY+oY);
context2D.rotate(rot * Math.PI / 180);
context2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, -(oX), -(oY), w, h);
context2D.restore();
}
```

Summary:

```
img: the image object
pX: the x position of the image
pY: the y position of the image
oX: how far across the image that the origin is
oY: how far down the image that the origin is
w: width of the image
h: height of the image
rot: angle of rotation
context2D: the context that have been build from the canvas
```